# Rendering output of SQLiteDatabase thrown by cursor to String[] array

Tags: java, android, database, string, sqlite

**This is my Android Project and got stacked**

My App has a DataBase with a `column(subname)` and two raw or `query(Physics, Chemistry)`

```
String[] subjects = {};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM subs", null);
if(c.moveToFirst()){
subjects[0] = c.getString(0);
                    }
```

I want output as two subjects as an array `{"Physics", "Chemistry"}`

But its only returning the first query Physics and its not returning the other column `Chemistry`.

How can I get the second value?

Comment: c.getString(0) only returns the value of 0th index.

Comment: what do you mean by **there are two raw or query(Physics, Chemistry)** ???? what is the datatype in table. Can you share complete structure of your table, current output and expected output

Comment: @PSN Are you saying the rows of Column 1?
Please answer.

Comment: You don't iterate your results. I don't see any attempt to output subjects. Could you correct your code? And please replace * on field name in SQL request

Comment: @AAShakil without understanding your question, how can someone answer.

Comment: @Ravi A column (Subname) has two row or value(Physics, Chemistry)
Thank you.

Comment: @AAShakil So, what do you want ??? what is your question ?? what is stoping you ?? Can you elaborate ??

Comment: @VladislavKysliy 
Thank you. c.getString(0); returns the accurate result (Physics, Chemistry) in EditText/TextView when I use append(c.getString(0));
But I don't have any idea to append those to String array.
As a beginner please help me bearing disturb.
Thank you.

Comment: @Ravi 
Thank you. c.getString(0); returns the accurate result (Physics, Chemistry) in EditText/TextView when I use append(c.getString(0));
But I don&#39;t have any idea to append those to String array.
As a beginner please help me bearing disturb.
Thank you.

Comment: @AAShakil Any specific reason to get result in Array ???

Comment: @Ravi I want to use those in an ListView using ArrayAdapter with those string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, number of rows can be 1, 2 or more, so we are not sure about the size of array. In this scenario, I would suggest to use `List` and then convert list to `Array`

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM subs", null);
if(c.moveToFirst())
{
    lst.add (c.getString(0));
}
```

Now convert `List` to `Array`

```
String[] arr = lst.toArray ();
```

Comment: Thanks ravi.
Could I get the two raws in an String array by this method?

Comment: @AAShakil yes, you will get. As I mentioned, we are not sure about array size. The best option would using list.

Comment: Sorry Ravi I have gone inactive..
But I don't have enough reputation to vote your Answer.

Comment: Yeah I have Made your answer as best but unable vote for low reputation, Sorry.